# How to avoid Creatine dependence?

Tags: diet, supplements, creatine, vegetarian

I am an vegetarian and ectomorph. I started taking Creatine after workouts for a while. And  it seems like I need to supplement creatine every day or else my body goes back to its old form.

Is there any natural way to  increase creatine production in our body without supplementation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, don't place too much value in your identification as an ectomorph. It belongs to a very old, and debunked myth about [somatotypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatotype_and_constitutional_psychology).

Now, the point of creatine isn't to gain a permanent weight increase. The point of creatine is to improve muscle recovery between sets by increasing their susceptibility to water, and thus their durability and stamina.

Another benefit of creatine is that you will likely experience increased energy levels during workouts, because of this recovery.

What creatine does NOT do, is provide permanent gains. You take creatine to maximize your workouts, and make better gains while under the effect of it. Then, when you stop taking creatine, you muscles will still have made those gains. You will lose the water weight (which I think you're confusing with going back to your "old form"), but the gains you made are there, unless you stop training all together.

As you probably know, meat and fish are the best sources of creatine, and even then, you'd have to get 500 grams per day to get the optimal amount of creatine. What you, as a vegetarian, should do, is get enough of the amino acids arginine, glycine, and methionine which are used in production of creatine.

Some foods that are rich in **glycene**: Raw seaweed, spirulina, raw watercress, spinach, soy protein isolate, sesame seeds.

Some foods that are rich in **arginine**: Peanuts, walnuts, coconuts, soybeans, chickpeas, oats.

Some good sources for **methionine**: Brazil nuts, oats, sunflower seeds.

For extra reading, I recommend [this page](http://www.veganhealth.org/articles/weightlifting) on vegan health and weightlifting.

Comment: Thanks. I heard that body produces creatine everyday but in small amounts. How to increase the creatine production of body through diet?

Comment: @alias_neo92 - I'll edit my answer. I can see that I skipped the part about increasing creatine production naturally.

Comment: @Alec - Good answer, but creatine doesn't really enhance recovery. What it does is increase the amount of creatine available in cells, to transform used up ADP back into ATP. It allows a person to work slightly longer and harder, which will increase eventual gains.

Comment: @JohnP - I'll be the first to admit I'm not the most informed when it comes to the translocates, but is it possible that the transformation could contribute to faster recovery?

Comment: Mmmm...it does, but not in the way you are thinking. It can make recovery between sets faster, but it doesn't build muscle faster in the recovery phase. It's an energy base/supplement, it doesn't really affect after workout recovery/muscle building.

Comment: @JohnP - Good stuff. I'll edit my answer.